# Why is Wordpress ignoring required field?

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I have a comment form under my posts where users must fill in their name and their email. In the page source it also shows the input field has `required="required"`. Yet the form still posts even when there is nothing inserted and does not show the supposed message which should work in HTML5. I am also checking the input server side but I like the default HTML5 messages so I would love them to work.
I'm currently using the latest WordPress version.

Comment: this is not enough to make the field required > I'd add a jquery validation, something like this > https://gist.github.com/leowebdev/491267f0dd67cd6e2ab9 and force the fields to be required.

Comment: I know, but I would like to do it with the html5 attribute.

Comment: That's how's suppose to be <input type="text" required name="bar" placeholder="required"> * doesn't work on safari and android > more info http://goo.gl/HByrAR

Comment: I already said I got that in my code, but the problem is it's not working even in compatible browsers.

Answer (score 2):

in function.php (delete: 'comment-form'):

```
add_theme_support('html5', array(
    'search-form',
    <s>'comment-form',</s>
    'comment-list',
    'gallery',
    'caption'
));
```

[form novalidate](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_novalidate.asp)

Answer (score 1):

you said > input type="text" required="required" name="bar" placeholder="required"

and I said > input type="text" required name="bar" placeholder="required"

there's a slightly difference, check and let me know.